# How can I give space on another drive to my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday for the first time. I gave 12.7GB to root and 8.8GB to home from a dual boot SSD with 128GB only that is shared with Windows 10.

I thought I could just redirect what I install to HDD afterwards but I don't think it's that simple.

Is there a way to give like 100GB from my 1TB HDD to store my installations in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes but not without cost.  You can make any directory mount on any drive, and migrate any directory to another drive/device. When you install using dpkg/apt tools they install on specific directories; which is one way to achieve it (by having directories on different drives).  This added complexity (changes to `/etc/fstab`) has costs (maintenance & problem solving should things go wrong), so if you're not sure how to do that, it's probably not a good idea for you.

Comment: Hum ok...so what's my best option? Delete ubuntu partitions from w10, and install again with root in ssd and home on the hdd?

Comment: @user535733 [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/) is in my opinion an inferior way to answer this question. Clearly it's a duplicate question, but if it gets closed it will be closed for the wrong reason because a better way of solving this specific problem exists. It's hard to be objective and egotistical at the same time without being labeled as opinion-based, but objectivity is my goal for this question.

Comment: Another option is linking folders back into /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk Probably better to then have /home as folder inside / instead of separate partition as then /home itself only has hidden files & folders for user settings, not all your data.

Comment: @CharlesGreen [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/) is in my opinion an inferior way to answer this question. Clearly it's some kind of a duplicate question, but the duplicate question is a blunt instrument that doesn't do a very good job of answering the specific question that askubuntu asked. For this reason I don't think it's an urgent necessity that this question be closed.

Comment: @karel Your answer is certainly more eloquent than what I marked as duplicate - I had seen something earlier in a discussion of where to place Home and User directories which was quite similar, but had forgotten that.  I have retracted my vote.

Comment: @earthmeLon we just reopened this.  Please retract close vote and delete comment...

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to redirect what you install to the HDD afterwards by using [custom folders](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories) for folders in `/home` in order to span your home directory across multiple hard disks. In your case the multiple hard disks are the 128GB SSD and the 1TB HDD.

Example (`xdg-user-dirs-update` - Update XDG user dir configuration):

```
 xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD /media/askubuntu/1TB-HDD/Downloads/
```

would switch from `/home/$USER/Downloads/` to `/media/askubuntu/1TB-HDD/Downloads/` and downloaded files would then download to the HDD and not to the SSD. The same applies for all the other directories.

> Both the local `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and global
>   `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` configuration files use the following
>   environmental variable format to point to user directories:
>   `XDG_DIRNAME_DIR="$HOME/directory_name"` An example configuration file
>   looks like this (these are all the template directories):
>
> Results of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` :
>
> ```
> XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
> XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
> XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
> XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
> XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
> XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
> XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
> XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
> ```
>
> As `xdg-user-dirs` will source the local configuration file to point
>   to the appropriate user directories, it is therefore possible to
>   specify custom folders. For example, if a custom folder for the
>   `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR` variable has been named `$HOME/Internet` in
>   `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` any application that uses this variable
>   will use this directory.